# How to change the Gateway Response in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, rest, aws-lambda, terraform

My rest API returns 403”Missing Authentication Token” when there is a typo issue in the URL.I want to edit the response to 404 “invalid resource”.
Note(I want to do the desired change using terraform not via aws console)

But not sure which terraform file I have to edit or change in order to the same any leads will be helpful

Comment: What have you tried already? Did you look for anything similar in the documentation?

Comment: I tried to look for any files or documents that might have error codes stated in them but haven't find anything yet.